# Python 3 modules and package relative import doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pytest

I have some difficulties constructing my project structure.

This is my project directory structure :

```
MusicDownloader/
   __init__.py
   main.py
   util.py
   chart/
      __init__.py
      chart_crawler.py
   test/
      __init__.py
      test_chart_crawler.py
```

These are codes :

1.main.py

```
from chart.chart_crawler import MelonChartCrawler

crawler = MelonChartCrawler()
```

2.test_chart_crawler.py

```
from ..chart.chart_crawler import MelonChartCrawler

def test_melon_chart_crawler():
  crawler = MelonChartCrawler()
```

3.chart_crawler.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/Chois/Desktop/Programming/Project/WebScrape/MusicDownloader")
from .. import util

class MelonChartCrawler:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
```

4.util.py

```
def hi():
   print("hi")
```

In MusicDownloader, when I execute main.py by `python main.py`, it shows errors:

```
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chart.chart_crawler import MelonChartCrawler
  File "/Users/Chois/Desktop/Programming/Project/WebScrape/MusicDownloader/chart/chart_crawler.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .. import util
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

But when I execute my test code in test directory by `py.test test_chart_crawler.py`, it works

When I first faced with absolute, relative imports, it seems like very easy and intuitive. But it drives me crazy now. Need your helps. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is `MusicDownloader` not being a package. Add `__init__.py` to `MusicDownloader` along with `main.py` and your relative import `..chart` should work. Relative imports work only inside packages, so you can't `..` to non-package folder.

Editing my post to provide you with more accurate answer to your answer edit.

It's all about the `__name__`. Relative imports use `__name__` of the module they are used in and the `from .(.)` part to form a full package/module name to import. Explaining in simple terms importer's `__name__` is concatenated with `from` part, with dots showing how many components of name to ignore/remove, i.e.:

`__name__='packageA.packageB.moduleA'` of the file containing line: `from .moduleB import something`, leads to combined value for import `packageA.packageB.moduleB`, so roughly `from packageA.packageB.moduleB import something`(but not absolute import as it would be if typed like that directly).

`__name__='packageA.packageB.moduleA'` of the file containing line: `from ..moduleC import something`, leads to combined value for import `packageA.moduleC`, so roughly `from packageA.moduleC import something`(but not absolute import as it would be if typed like that directly).

Here if it's a `moduleB(C)` or a `packageB(C)` doesn't really matter. What's important is that we still have that `packageA` part which works as an 'anchor' for relative import in both cases. If there will be no `packageA` part, relative import won't be resolved, and we'll get an error like "Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package".

One more note here, when a module is run it gets a special `__name__` value of `__main__`, which obviously prevents it from solving any relative imports.

Now regarding your case try adding `print(__name__)` as the very first line to every file and run your files in different scenarios and see how the output changes.

Namely if you run your main.py directly, you'll get:

```
__main__
chart.chart_crawler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MusicDownloader\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from chart.chart_crawler import MelonChartCrawler
  File "D:\MusicDownloader\chart\chart_crawler.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .. import util
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

What happened here is... `main.py` has no idea about `MusicDownloader` being a package (even after previous edit with adding `__init__.py`). In your `chart_crawler.py`: `__name__='chart.chart_crawler'` and when running relative import with `from ..` the combined value for package will need to remove two parts (one for every dot) as explained above, so the result will become `''` as there're just two parts and no enclosing package. This leads to exception.

When you import a module the code inside it is run, so it's almost the same as executing it, but without the `__name__` becoming `__main__` and the enclosing package, if there's any, being 'noticed'.

So, the solution is to import `main.py` as part of the `MusicDownloader` package. To accomplish the described above, create a module, say named `launcher.py` on the same level of hierarchy as `MusicDownloader` folder (near it, not inside it near `main.py`) with the following code:

```
print(__name__)
from MusicDownloader import main
```

Now run `launcher.py` and see the changes. The output:

```
__main__
MusicDownloader.main
MusicDownloader.chart.chart_crawler
MusicDownloader.util
```

Here `__main__` is the `__name__` inside `launcher.py`. Inside `chart_crawler.py`: `__name__='MusicDownloader.chart.chart_crawler'` and when running relative import with `from ..` the combined value for package will need to remove two parts (one for every dot) as explained above, so the result will become `'MusicDownloader'` with import becoming `from MusicDownloader import util`. And as we see on the next line when `util.py` is imported successfully it prints its `__name__='MusicDownloader.util'`.

So that's pretty much it - "it's all about that `__name__`".

P.S. One thing not mentioned is why the part with `test` package worked. It wasn't launched in common way, you used some additional module/program to lauch it and it probably imported it in some way, so it worked. To understand this it's best to see how that program works.

There's a note in [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references):

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current module. Since the name of the main module is always "__main__", modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application must always use absolute imports.

Comment: Just adding `__init__.py` make it works! By the way, when I `print(sys.path)` in my `test_chart_crawler.py`,  `PYTHONPATH` doesn't have not just `test` directory  but `MusicDownloader` directory. It just has parent dir of `MusicDownloader`...

Comment: Nice that I could help. PYTHONPATH is calculated dynamically, so there are things that affect it, including where your code resides considering absolute path.

Comment: Hey, I'm faced with same kind of problem again. I edited my post... I have no idea what is the principle of relative import...T _ T

Comment: I really really appreciate your detailed answer and kindness. Thanks a lot.
But If I follow your instruction(adding launcher.py),   
1. I have to correct code in main.py : from `from chart.chart_crawler import MelonChartCrawler` to `from .chart.chart_crawler import MelonChartCrawler` (adding dot)
2. The project folder structure is not good. There are two starter files.. `launcher.py` and `main.py`
Information about `__name__` really helps, but I have to look up some easy example opensource project or books. If you know any, could you recommand?

Comment: After I solved these two problems, I'll gonna select your answers. Thanks alot again.

Comment: Glad that I could help. I copied the structure and code you provided and tested before answering, and it worked without the change in import you describe. If you want to use relative imports, there's really no more good option that I know of, than creating a separate launch script. Relative imports were introduced to make easy imports inside packages, that get imported themself. And you have and "executeble" module, so the solution is to import it. You'll have only one "main script": - `launcher.py` with single import statement, and all the code in `main.py`.

Comment: Other solution is to use absolute imports and `.pth` file. Relative imports are not that easy as they seem, in fact, as all of Python, when you try to understand it in depth and learn some more advanced technics. Many people have problems with relative imports, so there're a lot of articles on the net, that you can read. In general, if you want to understand Python more than just that is shown in countless tutorials read Python docs https://docs.python.org/3/.

Comment: Also, a good book is Learning Python by Mark Lutz. I like it and hate it at the same time - it covers important things in nice details. But you have to dig for those gems there, because there's a lot of repetition of introductory sentences everywhere, I mean  A LOT, and the essence of information could be compresed to 1/3 to 1/2 of it's volume. Looks like Mark Lutz got paid by the number of words. Oh, Pro Python by Marty Alchin is also quite good, less detailed explanation, but more practical.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. You're really good person! I'll study package and module more and will be back to this issue again   :)